# Can I have 2 different forms of the same tree?

Tags: avl-tree, red-black-tree

If have example numbers 54, 23, 5, 65, 76, 34, 87 and I want to insert them in an AVL or redblack tree can I have 2 different forms of the same tree for example 2 different AVL tree?

Comment: What do you mean by the form of a tree?

Comment: for example in an avl tree at the one maybe the left child is bf +1 and in the other is bf -1 and its still a proper avl tree both trees with the same numbers on

Comment: Well, if you use standard (deterministic) implementation, that is, there're no random choices made when making changes to a tree, then you end up with the same tree for same sequences of operations.

Comment: Ok thank you for your time, you answerd my question have a nice day. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I posted as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use standard (deterministic) implementation, that is, there're no random choices made when making changes to a tree, then you end up with the same tree for same sequences of operations.